# Updating SortOrder using Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sorting, linq-to-sql

I have a table wherein i have some products, user are provided with the up and down buttons to sort the products as per their requirement and the products will be visible on site in that order only

I had written a stored procedure to update the sortorder, but now as i have converted my website to the Linq to Sql, i am stuck with how to update the sortorder based on the user's action.

Here's my stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[user_SortProductsOrder]
    @CurrentSortOrder INT,
    @TempSortOrder INT,
    @TownId INT,
    @SectionId INT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE HomePageSectionSettings SET SortOrder = 
    CASE SortOrder  WHEN @TempSortOrder THEN @CurrentSortOrder
                    WHEN @CurrentSortOrder THEN @TempSortOrder
                    ELSE SortOrder
    END
    WHERE TownId = @TownId
        AND SectionId = @SectionId
END
```

below is what i am trying using Linq to Sql but in vain.

```
var updateSortOrder = db.HomePageSectionSettings.Where(item => item.TownId == int.Parse(drpTowns.SelectedValue) && item.SectionId == int.Parse(drpSectionName.SelectedValue)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (updateSortOrder.SortOrder == tempSortOrder)
        {
            updateSortOrder.SortOrder = currentSortOrder;
        }
        else if (updateSortOrder.SortOrder == currentSortOrder)
        {
            updateSortOrder.SortOrder = tempSortOrder;
        }
        db.SubmitChanges();
```

I can understand something is going wrong with the if logic, but i am unable to come to correct conclusion

Can anyone help to repair this logic.

Comment: Have you debugged it to check what is coming to updateSortOrder?

Comment: may be none of your conditions is met.